# Grouped Product Discounts

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

We have a Grouped product that consists of 3 books. When the customer selects the grouped product, they are given checkboxes to select each of the three books and they get placed in the cart as three separate line items.

We have a Shopping Cart Price rule that discounts the "group" by $20.

Now, when the customer selects a single group, the discount is applied. But then they select more than one of the grouped products, the discount is only being applied once.

How can I make that discount apply to ALL?

Here's the Conditions and Actions:
[image: Conditions & Actions]

Comment: Is it your problem solved !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all the other people out there struggling with this issue...

I had to change to using a percentage and removed the max:
[image: New Actions]

Works on any number of products.

Comment: not working for me, am doing  set percentage and removed the max, help me

Comment: @ MB34 : Help me, not work for me

Answer (score 0):

**Need to some changes your shopping cart rule settings**

Please follow settings same as bellow attached screen shot 1 & 2

[image]

[image]

Comment: That takes off $20 for EACH BOOK. I want $20 for each GROUP.

Comment: No other ideas??

Comment: @MB34 : did u get answer ?

Comment: Not exactly. I still do not believe that it works as initially thought.